Cup board a little discolored
I tried to wash my cupboard and used a little too much water and this is the result:

It's worse in the picture than in real life (I used a super high resolution camera) but still, I don't like it. Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks
P.S. I can swap out this door if I need to righ? The color match and all? The size is exactly 1 foot X 3 feet X 5/8 inch.
Also, it's attache with these cupboard hinges? You know what I mean? Is it going to be very hard to align the new board on those hinges?
